# Banding artifacts in CNN

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, image-processing, image-generation

I was working on a CNN for HDR image generation from LDR images. I used an encoder-decoder architecture and merged the input with the decoder output. However I'm getting some banding artifacts in the model prediction as shown.

1)Input LDR image

[image: Input LDR Image]

2) Ground Truth HDR

[image: Ground Truth HDR]

3) Predicted output

[image: Predicted Output]

Notice the fine bands in the prediction. What might be causing these bands? Also I trained only for 20 epochs yet. Is the problem due to inadequate training?
Here's my model:

```
 class TestNet2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestNet2, self).__init__()

    def enclayer(nIn, nOut, k, s, p, d=1):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(nIn, nOut, k, s, p, d), nn.SELU(inplace=True)
        )
    def declayer(nIn, nOut, k, s, p):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(nIn, nOut, k, s, p), nn.SELU(inplace=True)
        )

    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        enclayer(3,64,5,3,1),
        #nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
        enclayer(64,128,5,3,1),
        #nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
        enclayer(128,256,5,3,1),
        #nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
    )
    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        declayer(256,128,5,3,1),
        declayer(128,64,5,3,1),
        declayer(64,3,5,3,1),


    )

  def forward(self, x):
      xc=x
      x = self.encoder(x)
      x = self.decoder(x)
      x = F.interpolate(
        x, (512, 512), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False
      )
      x=x+xc
      return x
```